# Webkit shadows textarea when tapping on element

Tags: ios, css, uiwebview, textarea

I'm building an iOS app that uses a webview in one place. When the user taps on an textarea and the keyboard appears the textarea get a shadowing highlight effect and then goes back to normal. Please note that I'm not talking about webkit-appearance och outline, but the shadow that covers the whole textarea being tapped.

I'm guessing this is some kind of accessibility feature. Still, it mess up my animation and makes the whole view look like crap.

Does anyone know if it's possible to remove this highlight shadow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable it by setting the css attribute -webkit-tap-highlight-color to rgba(0,0,0,0);
But as you mentioned it is a usability feature, so you should not turn it off. ;)

See:
http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/10/01/quick-tip-customizing-the-mobile-safari-tap-highlight-color/